# PHP code not working in IE8

Tags: php, forms, internet-explorer

I've got a baffling IE8 PHP problem. The code below works fine in chrome and FF but not IE8. The form is submitting, errors are displayed if no search term or check-boxes selected, and if both db searches fail the No Actors and No Movies found echo's are both displayed. But if either one of the searches is successful nothing is displayed, not even the Actors/Movies found echo which has me stumped.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
if($_POST[submitbutton]){
    $search = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[search]));

    if(!$search){
        echo "Please enter a search term!";
    }else if(!$_POST['checkbox']){
        echo "Please select at least one database to search!";
    }else{
        //search names
        if(in_array("actors", $_POST['checkbox'])){
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT name_id, realname, mainalias FROM names WHERE realname LIKE '%$search%' OR mainalias LIKE '%$search%'");

            if(mysql_num_rows($query)==0){
                echo "<h2>No Actors by that name found!</h2>", "<p>";
            }else{
                echo "<h2>Actors Found:</h2>";
                while ($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                    $realname = $record['realname'];
                    $name_id = $record['name_id'];
                    echo "<a href='index.php?page=name&id=$name_id'>", $realname, "</a><hr>";
                }
            }
        }

        //search titles
        if(in_array("movies", $_POST['checkbox'])){
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT title_id, title FROM titles WHERE title LIKE '%$search%'");

            if(mysql_num_rows($query)==0){
                echo "<h2>No Movies by that name found!</h2>", "<p>";
            }else{
                echo "<h2>Movies Found:</h2>";
                while ($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                    $title = $record['title'];
                    $title_id = $record['title_id'];
                    echo "<a href='index.php?page=title&amp;id=$title_id'>", $title, "</a><br>";

                echo "<hr>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
} //end post submitbutton
?>
```

Comment: This calls for basic debugging first - which conditions and loops are hit when the screen is blank?

Comment: Is this accurate: `$_POST[submitbutton]`? That is likely an error. Should be something like `$_POST['submitbutton']`.

Comment: Same thing with `$_POST[search]` in line 3.

Comment: `if($_POST[submitbutton])` must be `if($_POST['submitbutton'])`

Comment: With the exception of the window-licking idiocy that IE6 displayed when handling `<button>` elements in forms, there's no way the choice of browser could affect whether or not a script on the server side runs properly.

Comment: The web browser does not care about PHP. It wants to consume HTML. So check that out first. That would identify the bug.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments and bug spotting. Just want to let everyone know the source of the problem is the if($_POST['submitbutton']) statement at the start of the script. Take it out and it works perfectly every time.

Answer (score 0):

Should

```
$search = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[search]));
```

be

```
$search = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']));
```

I don't know if that has anything to do with your problem, but it jumper out at me.

Comment: Although it is **very** bad practice to not use quotes for named keys in PHP, I don't think this would cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitbutton'], $_POST['search'])){ //use isset for check exists vars
    $search = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search'])); // ['POST vars']

    if(!$search){
        echo "Please enter a search term!";
    }else if(!isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
        echo "Please select at least one database to search!";
    }else{
        //search names
        if(in_array("actors", $_POST['checkbox'])){
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT name_id, realname, mainalias FROM names WHERE realname LIKE '%$search%' OR mainalias LIKE '%$search%'");

            if(mysql_num_rows($query)==0){
                echo "<h2>No Actors by that name found!</h2>", "<p>";
            }else{
                echo "<h2>Actors Found:</h2>";
                while ($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                    $realname = $record['realname'];
                    $name_id = $record['name_id'];
                    echo "<a href='index.php?page=name&id=$name_id'>", $realname, "</a><hr>";
                }
            }
        }

        //search titles
        if(in_array("movies", $_POST['checkbox'])){
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT title_id, title FROM titles WHERE title LIKE '%$search%'");

            if(mysql_num_rows($query)==0){
                echo "<h2>No Movies by that name found!</h2>", "<p>";
            }else{
                echo "<h2>Movies Found:</h2>";
                while ($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                    $title = $record['title'];
                    $title_id = $record['title_id'];
                    echo "<a href='index.php?page=title&amp;id=$title_id'>", $title, "</a><br>";

                echo "<hr>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
} //end post submitbutton
?>
```